# Delete empty cells (very slow)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Range where I want to delete all empty cells. I developed the following solution but it is very very slowly. Could anyone help me to understand why this is so solw and what approach would lead to a faster solution.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = letzte2 To 4 Step -1
        For j = 2 To 17
            If tab6.Cells(i, j) = "" Then
            tab6.Cells(i, j).Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform only one **Delete** :

```
Dim rDel As Range
Set rDel = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = Letzte2 To 4 Step -1
        For j = 2 To 17
            If tab6.Cells(i, j) = "" Then
                If rDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rDel = tab6.Cells(i, j)
                Else
                    Set rDel = Union(rDel, tab6.Cells(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
If Not rDel Is Nothing Then
    rDel.Delete shift:=xlUp
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easy (and effective) by using the `SpecialCells()` method. The following deletes all empty cells in a selection.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyCells()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```